# Do Salesforce Console Integration API Calls Count Towards Request Limits?

Tags: limits, custom-console-components

As the title says, do calls to the Salesforce Console Integration API, for example `getSelectedNavigationTab()`, count towards API limits for users?

I've stepped through the code as much as possible and I'm 99% sure it's being handled locally but the documentation does mention 'calls to the server' in a couple of places and I'm not sure about those requests (I'm not sure which ones those are, it's just talking about the asynchonous nature of the API).

Note that I'm talking about Custom Console Components, *NOT* the Developer Console!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got an answer from Mike Hineline, a Sales Engineer at Salesforce ([via tweets](https://twitter.com/mikehineline/status/553372825025642496), hence the short sentences!):

> There are no governor limits with JavaScript functions in the
>   Salesforce Console Integration Toolkit. Similar to how JavaScript
>   remoting doesn't count against your API limits. Note that if you're
>   invoking things like push notifications, you may have other limits to
>   consider.

Comment: Possible for you to permalink his tweet in this reply for the future?

Comment: Yeah I'll dig it out now.. I was on a rather basic client at the time. Also, it was 3 tweets.